# Epson SureColor P800 printing black and white photos greenish

Tags: color-management

I am trying to print black and white photos and the prints have a greenish hue.

These are photos that I had printed before. They printed correctly in the past (just black, white and grays, no other colors). Now they print green.

**What I tried:**

- From PS and from LR: same results.

  With different profiles, and also managed by printer: same results.

  Different papers, several matte papers and also plain paper: same
  greenish tint in all papers I tried.

  I made a screenshot (I am desperate!) and printed from Preview: same
  green!

**In the printer:**

All ink levels and print heads are okay.

Maintenance cartridge was expended, when I took the old one was very GREEN dirty. I replaced it by a clean new one now, but prints continue to have the green tint.

Comment: What about colour photos? Do they print with any hue or colour cast?

Comment: I just tested with a color photo, and at least this one looks good.

Comment: Epson heads are in the printer, not the cartridge. Changing the cartridge does not unclog clogged heads with Epson printers. Your magenta head is probably clogged, thus too much green (cyan + yellow) is being used compared to magenta.

Comment: @Michael C Printer heads are okay as said in the post. Nozzle check gives perfect lines, all colors included Vivid Magenta and Vivid Light Magenta. Do you mean something else?